# Redewendung für „for my records“ oder „for my files“?

Tags: english-to-german, expression

Die englische Redewendung „for my records“ (oder „for my files“) wird in den Staaten oft verwendet. Gibt es auch eine ähnliche deutsche Redewendung, die oft verwendet wird?

„Für meine Akte“ ist mir sofort eingefallen und, nachdem ich das Web durchsucht habe, ist es das einzige Suchergebnis, dass ich sinnvoll finde oder von dem ich denke, dass es vielleicht weit verbreitet ist.

Gibt es bessere oder häufiger verwendete Redewendungen?

Comment: Eine Nachfrage: Wird hier nach "[for my records](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62533/meaning-of-for-your-record)" oder eher doch nach "[for the record](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=For%20The%20Record)" gefragt? Ähnlichkeit + Verwechslungsgefahr ist ja da.

Comment: @mtwde "For the record" bedeutet was anderes: "fürs Protokoll"

Comment: @PiedPiper deswegen die Nachfrage, ob keine Verwechslung besteht. Ohne Vorwurf an den OP, sondern Interesse an der Frage

Comment: Ich habe die Überschrift jetzt fünf Mal gelesen: Wo ist der Unterschied der beiden Begriffe links und rechts des "oder"?

Comment: Ich glaube, gemeint ist: „for my records“ (oder „for my files“) wie unten im "bottom".

Answer (score 10):

Ich würde meinen, dass die Standard-Bezeichnung dafür ist

> für meine Unterlagen

Das sind Dokumente aller Art, zum Beispiel von Behörden, Banken oder Unternehmen. Manchmal steht auf Dokumenten oder Durchschlägen auch explizit »für Ihre Unterlagen« drauf.

Comment: Sehr häufig hört man auch einfach nur: *»Für mich«*

Answer (score 0):

Der Antwort von @konst möchte ich hinzufügen, dass je nach Kontext auch

> - für meine Notizen
> - für meine Aufzeichnungen

passen könnte. Den ersten Ausdruck verwende ich selbst recht häufig, zum Beispiel wenn ich am Ende einer Besprechung ausgedruckte Abbildungen, Skizzen oder Handgeschriebenes zusammenraffe und so etwas sage wie: *„Ich nehm' das mal mit für meine Notizen.“*